Count value from a multi drop down menu in sheet
I'm building a spreadsheet of my personal game library in Google Sheets. I'm trying to extract the most frequently occurring genre across all games. I've created a multi-select dropdown menu to choose genres for each game. However, I'm having trouble counting genres when multiple are selected for a single game.
Current formula (which doesn't work with multi-select):
=CONCATENATE( INDEX(Games[Genre], MODE(MATCH(Games[Genre], Games[Genre], 0))), " (", COUNTIF(Games[Genre], INDEX(Games[Genre], MODE(MATCH(Games[Genre], Games[Genre], 0)))), " games)" )
This formula works fine for single-select, but when I select multiple genres for a game, it doesn't register all selections and doesn't add them up correctly.
Example of my data:
Game 1: Action, RPG
Game 2: FPS, Action
Game 3: RPG
Game 4: Action, FPS
Expected result: "Action (3 games)"
Actual result: The formula only counts the first genre in each cell, so it might return "Action (2 games)" instead.
How can I modify this formula to correctly count genres in a multi-select scenario, where genres in a single cell are separated by commas?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Count of Games Matching Criteria from Filtered List
I created one spreadsheet with two sheets. Sheet 1 contains game titles and genres,
while Sheet 2 shows the total number of selected genres.
Here’s the sample for Sheet 1:

You can add as many game titles and genres as you want.
In Column C, I have entered the output or selected genres from Column B. The formula used is
=TRIM(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, SPLIT(B2, ", ")))

Here’s the sample for Sheet 2: It summarizes or counts the total number of selections for each genre, displaying the results according to your needs.

The formula used is:
=TEXT(COUNTIF(FLATTEN(SPLIT(JOIN(", ", FILTER(Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!B:B <> "")), ", ")), A$1), "0") & " games"

This formula shows how many game choices match the selected genres based on the dropdown choices in Column B of Sheet 1.
If you add another genre, input it in a new column. Then, update the value in A$1 to match the column where you added the genre. For example, if you add a genre in column E, change the reference in A$1 to E$1.
Reference

TEXTJOIN

JOIN

SPLIT FUNCTION


